# Unsolicited logins are not allowed

Tags: sitecore-client, identity-server, adfs

My Sitecore application(10.2) is integrated with ADFS. Currently, the application intermittently returns an error, `Unsolicited logins are not allowed,` when users attempt to log in. Could anyone assist how in resolving this issue?

Please refer to the attached pictures for more details.
[image]

I followed the article to integrate ADFS with Sitecore.
https://360agileweb.dev/2020/03/02/sitecore-host-part-four/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47798431/1277533 Related?

Comment: Not related to the issue i facing.

Comment: @Alex add error details or stack trace as text for SEO.